# Error when not providing author name with apa7

Tags: titles, author, apa7

I am using the `apa7` class for submitting a manuscript for blind peer review, so naturally, I cannot have any author names anywhere. When I do

```
\author{}
```

I get an error that says `LaTeX error: there's no line here to end`. When I change the above line to

```
\author{anything}
```

the error disappears. But of course, I can't put `anything` in the title page. The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[man, hidelinks, floatsintext]{apa7}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\let\OldMaketitle\maketitle
\let\OldNewpage\newpage
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
   \renewcommand\newpage{\let\newpage\OldNewpage}% <----- Eliminate the effect of first \newpage
   \OldMaketitle%
}

\title{Title of Document}
\shorttitle{RUNNING HEAD}
\author{}
\affiliation{}
\abstract{\lipsum[1]}
\keywords{keyword1, keyword2}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: PDFs don't actually include spaces, so you could just do `\author{\ }` or if you want to recover the vertical space: `\author{\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}\ }`. But honestly if it were I'd probably do something like `\author{(Submitted for anonymous review.)}` to occupy that space temporarily, or just leave the `\author` command out, in which case it just prints "Author" in that spot. But this is temporary issue; don't sweat it.

Comment: I know I shouldn't be, it's just irks me off to see an annoying error haha. `\author{\\ }` worked for me.